# Debug webpack.config.babel.js in vscode

Tags: javascript, webpack, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug a webpack.config.babel.js. I can't figure out how to do it.
The "normal" es5 webpack.config.js works fine with this config in vs code:

```
"configurations": [

{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Launch Webpack",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js",
  "args": [
    "--config", "${workspaceFolder}/webpack.config.js"
 ]
}
]
```

Tips highly appreciated =)

Comment: What is the problem that you have that you need to debug?

Comment: currently no problem. I did some filereading and writing and debugging would have been very helpful.
It would also help with more complex entries and outputs